# identify portable executable

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, exe, policy

I want to write a program that allows or blocks processes while openning a file depending on a policy.

I could make a control by checking the name of the program. However, it would not be enough because user can change the name to pass the policy. i.e. let's say that policy doesn't allow a.exe to access txt files whereas b.exe is allowed. If user change a.exe with b.exe, i cannot block it.

On the other hand, verifying portable executable signature is not enough for me, because i don't care whether the executable signed or not. I just want to identify the executable that is wanted to execute even its name is changed.

For this type of case, what would you propose? Any solutions are welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a [hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) to identify executables.

Comment: @arx I had thought that, but it requires being up to date for all versions of considered executables. Also, i checked ms office 2007 (winword.exe) as an example in three different computer whether their length are same or not. They were all different. That made me think that executable of same application may differ in different computers depending on some reasons.

Comment: There will be lots of versions of winword.exe depending on, for example, what updates have been applied.  But it shouldn't be different on *every* computer.  Any other way of identifying an unsigned exe (e.g. the name in the version resource) is easily spoofed.

Comment: You've discounted signature checking, but how else do you want to confirm it's a safe executable? Why sign them yourself and check the signature matches yours.

Comment: Either you identify the file you want to block by a behavior, either by what it is (a bunch of bytes). Basically antivirus software do this also (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antivirus_software 'Identification Methods'). In your case, if you can't match by a specific behavior, you're left with the file's bytes.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to identify an executable file. Here is a simple list:

**Name:**

The most simple and straightforward approach is to identify a file by its name. But it is one of the easiest things to change, and you already ruled that out.

**Date:**

Files have an access, creation, and modification date, and they are managed by the operating system. They are not foolproof, or maybe not even accurate.
Also, they are very simple to change.

**Version Information:**

Since we are talking about executable files, then most executable files have version information attached to it. For example, original file name, file version, product version, company, description, etc. You can check these fields if you are sure the user cannot modify them by editing your executable. It doesn't require you to keep a database of allowed files. However, it does require you to have something to compare to, like company name, or a product name. Also, If someone made an executable with the same value
they can run instead of the allowed one and bypass your protection.

**Location:**

If the file is located in a specific place and is protected by file system access rights, and it cannot be changed, then you can use that. You can, for example, put the allowed files in a folder where the user (without admin rights) can only read/execute them, but not rename/move. Then identify the file with its location. If it is run from this location, then allow it, else block it. It is good as it doesn't need a database of
allowed/blocked files, it just compares the location, it it is a valid one, then allow, and you can keep adding and removing files to allowed locations
without affecting your program.

**Size:**

If the file has a specific file size, you can quickly check its size and compare it. But it is unreliable as files can be changed/patched and without any change in size. You can avoid that by also applying a CRC check to detect if the content of the file changed.
But, both size and CRC can be changed. Also, this requires you to have a list of file names and their sizes/CRC, and keeping it up to date.

**Signature:**

Deanna mentioned that you can self-sign your executable files. Then check if the signature matches yours and allow/deny based on that. This seems to be a good way if
it is okay for you to sign all the executable files you want to allow. It doesn't require you to keep an updated list of allowed files.

**Hash:**

arx also pointed out, that you can hash the files. It is one of the slowest methods, as it requires the file to be hashed every time it is executed, then compared to a list of files. But it very reliable as it can uniquely identify each file and hard to break. But, you will need to keep an up to date database of every file hash.

Finally, and depend on your needs and options, you can mix two or more ways together to get the results you want. Like, checking file name + location, etc.

I hope I covered most of things, but I'm sure there are more ways. Anyone can freely edit my post to include anything that I have missed.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the signature, if it has one, or the hash otherwise.  Apps such as Office that update frequently are more likely to be signed, whereas smaller apps downloaded off the Internet are unlikely to ever be updated and so should have a consistent hash.